# Why is there an error when passing an object consisting of a file path to the image and setting in bg-[url()] tailwindcss?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

[image: This is the issue where I am passing the path, which is save in category.bgimg, and is showing this error]

[image]
The image is also exploding on load then adjust itself.
And if you could explain the alternate way to use next js Image tag to set the background and have the animation set to the section.

I tried console.log(category.bgimg) and it give the output

Comment: Include your code/errors as text

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Thus, with regards to the error, Tailwind interprets the class `bg-[url(${category.bgimg})]` literally:

```css
.bg-\[url\(\$\{category.bgimg\}\)\] {
  background-image: url(${category.bgimg});
}
```

and as the error suggests, Next cannot find this file named `${category.bgimg}` *literally*.

To work around this, consider using the `style` attribute:

```
<motion.section
  …
  style={{ backgroundImage: category.bgimg }}
>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, for clearing it out.  I save the image with the whole tag. So it worked